# Metropolis-Hastings kernel in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory, algorithms, markov-chains

I'm facing difficulties in formulating the Metropolis-Hastings kernel for a specific problem where I need to sample from a probability distribution involving both discrete and continuous degrees of freedom (e.g., a state $s=(x,c)$ representing the position $x$ of a particle and its colour $c$).

1. Is it safe to assume that this probability has a density $p$ with respect to some generic measure $\mu$ on the space $(S,\Sigma)$?
2. Can I define the proposal kernel $Q$ to be $Q(s,A)$ for $A\subset S$? E.g. say I draw my proposal $s'=(x',c')$ by sampling $x'$ from a gaussian and $c'$ from a Bernoulli.
3. Can I assume this proposal kernel has density $q$ with respect to the same measure $\mu$? I'd say this measure is neither the Lebesgue nor the counting measure as the measure space is neither discrete nor continuous.
4. Can I then write the Metropolis-hastings ratio as
   $$
   r(x,x')=\frac{p(x')q(x',x)}{p(x)q(x,x')},
   $$
   that is, using the densities with respect to $\mu$ and not the measures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You asked another question that seems somewhat likely to be closed for not being research-level mathematics. I will include my posted answer to that here because that one may get closed.

One does not call a "measurable space" $(S,\Sigma)$ "discrete" or "continuous", although one may call a particular measure on that space "discrete" or "continuous".

You seem to suggest that the $x$ component of $s=(x,c)$ may take values in $\mathbb R^n$ and $c$ may be a Bernoulli random variable, i.e. $c\in\{0,1\}.$ In that case the proposal kernel would typically have a density with respect to the **product measure** whose two factors are Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ and counting measure on $\{0,1\}.$ So your point #2 seems unproblematic.

**Appendix: How I answered that other question**

A discrete probability distribution is one made up entirely of point masses; i.e. there is some set $S_1\subseteq S$ for which, for every $s\in S_1,$ the probability $P\{s\}$ assigned to the set $\{s\}$ is positive, and $\sum_{s\in S_1} P\{s\} = 1.$

A probability measure $P$ is a mixture – a weighted average – of a discrete probability distribution and a distribution with no discrete part precisely if $\sum_{s\in S_1} P\{s\}<1$ where $S_1 = \{ s\in S : P\{s\}>0\} \ne\varnothing. $

A probability distribution has no discrete part if for all $s\in S,$ $P\{s\}=0.$

In all of the above I avoided the word "continuous." More on that below.

There is nothing in your description that implies that a probability measure on your space has any discrete part.

If $X$ is a random variable taking values in the space you describe, certainly the $c$ component of $X$ – call it $c(X)$ – is a random variable whose probability distribution is discrete.

But that doesn't mean $X$ itself has a positive probability of being at any one point.

"Continuous" can mean having a density, which in many contexts is equivalent to being absolutely continuous with respect to some underlying measure. Having a density is always a sufficient condition for absolute continuity.

But sometimes "continuous" means having a continuous cumulative distribution function. That is a sufficient condition for having no discrete part, but does not entail that there is a density function.

Comment: Thank you very much. So, to sum up

1. The target distribution has density wrt the same product measure (Lebesgue times counting), right?
4. Is the ratio correct in this form if $q$ is the density wrt to this product measure?

Comment: I might have to think about "4", but "1" is correct for most proposal kernels that I would expect to see in use.